# DateTime is not inserting into the database using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, jsp

I am using jsp file and mysql. I have problem inserting date and time into my database. I can insert the other information but only the date&time. I need to insert the date and time into my database too. How can I achieve it? Any help is appreciated.

**Jsp Code**

```
 <% 
            String userId       = request.getParameter("UserID");
            String arm          = request.getParameter("Arm");
            String[] armNumber  = request.getParameterValues("ArmNumber");
            String remark       = request.getParameter("Remark");
            String Timestamp    = request.getParameter("Time");


            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
            out.println(Timestamp);
            out.println("</td>");
            out.println("</tr>");


            int count           =0;
            Connection conn     = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Dodo?user=Dodo&password=0000";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

                if (armNumber != null){

                for(int i=0; i<armNumber.length; i++){

                        String sql="Insert into assign(UserID, Arm, ArmNumber, Remark, Time) Values(?,?,?,?,now())";
                        PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                        pstmt.setString (1,userId);
                        pstmt.setString (2,arm);
                        pstmt.setString (3,(armNumber[i]));
                        pstmt.setString (4,remark);

                    int rec=pstmt.executeUpdate();

                    if (rec==1)
                        count++;
                    }
                }
    %>


            <form action="assign.jsp" method="post">
                <label><%=count%> assigned!!</label>
                <td style width="50%">
                <p><input type="submit" value="Return" name="ReturnBtn" /></p>
            </form>


    <%
            conn.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{

            }
    %>
```

Comment: What is the type of `Time` in your database ?

Comment: datetime @AvijitBarua

Comment: Then try my answer

Comment: You need to convert datetime tomy sql date time format

Comment: How do i convert that? @sumesh TG

Comment: You are used `now()` in query itself so mysql will insert current time to row.

Comment: What does the timestamp string that you get from `request.getParameter("Time")` look like? I mean what format has it got? I suggest you parse it into an appropriate datetime object, convert it to `Instant` and use `pstmt.setObject(5, yourInstant)`; to pass it to the database (provided you are using at least Java 8 and at least JDBC 4.2, which you probably are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write `sql` statement like

```
String sql="Insert into assign(UserID, Arm, ArmNumber, Remark, Time) Values(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Then add some extra statement  under `pstmt.setString (4,remark);`

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
pstmt.setDate(5,dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. but there is an error on the "DateFormat', so i have changed it to "SimpleDateFormat". However, there is an error for "setDate"

Comment: @Rachelk I forgot to add position number  `5` . Check now !

Comment: I have tried that, but it shows this error  **Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The method setDate(int, Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the 
  arguments (int, String)
 - The method setDate(int, Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the 
  arguments (int, String)"** @Avijit Barua

Comment: I have write that statement in. However, it has an error @avijit barua

Comment: I did tried using  `pstmt.setDate(5,date); ` It has the same error @Avijit Barua

Comment: I shows more error when i use `java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(); `

Comment: Try this `ps.setDate(5, java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now()));` or `ps.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));`

Comment: It's still not working, is it because of other problems? @Avijit Barua

Comment: I don't know. Please check your database time type. Make sure that type is `DATETIME`

Comment: Ya, its "DATETIME"

Comment: Did you import `import java.sql.*;` ?

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V.
Your suggestion will be in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

`now()` is included in `sql` which is a `String`, I assume you were looking for a method called `now()` which returns the current time and date, but because it's inside a `String` it's not calling the method. You need to do the following:

```
String sql="Insert into assign(UserID, Arm, ArmNumber, Remark, Time) Values(?,?,?,?,?)";
....
pstmt.setString(1,userId);
pstmt.setString(2,arm);
pstmt.setString(3,(armNumber[i]));
pstmt.setString(4,remark);
pstmt.setTimestamp(5, new Date());//this is java.util.Date
```

Comment: Thank for guiding, but how do you create a method for `now()` which returns the current time and date. Because i do not have that method @mohammedkhan